# Why semaphore is released but WaitForSingleObject() still stuck?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, semaphore

**UPDATE:** I found that the semaphore they are releasing is not the semaphore the monitor thread is waiting! I used `cout<<ready` to find the semaphore the threads are releasing is `00000394`, which is not the handle of the semaphore the monitor thread is waiting for. What is the possible reason for this problem? Thank you!

---

I am new to multithread programming in Windows. Today when I'm writing my online game server, I try to use semaphores in Windows. It is written based on IOCP so that every message is handled in a separate thread. A game consists 4 players.

What I expect it to do is: when receiving a message, a new thread starts and release a `ready`. There is a monitor thread waiting for 4 `ready`, and then releases 4 `all_ready`. Each thread waits one `all_ready` and goes on.

The code is here:

`CGameHost` is a manager for a 4-player game.

```
CGameHost::CGameHost(void)
{
    init_times=0;
    ready = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4, NULL);
    read = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4, NULL);
    all_ready = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4, NULL);
    all_read = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 4, NULL);
    monitor_thread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Monitor, (LPVOID)this, NULL, 0);
}

unsigned __stdcall CGameHost::Monitor( LPVOID p ) // a static function
{
    CGameHost *nowp = (CGameHost *)p;
    while(true)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<=MAX_PLAYER;i++)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(nowp->ready, INFINITE);//stuck here
            cout<<"Get Ready!"<<endl; // This is not outputed, which means it stucks in the last row.
        }

        for(i=1;i<=MAX_PLAYER;i++)
        {
            ReleaseSemaphore(nowp->all_ready, 1, NULL);
        }

        for(i=1; i<=MAX_PLAYER; i++)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(nowp->read, INFINITE);
        }

        for(i=1; i<=MAX_PLAYER;i++)
        {
            ReleaseSemaphore(nowp->all_read, 1, NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void CGameHost::ReleaseReady()
{
    ReleaseSemaphore(ready, 1, NULL);
}

void CGameHost::WaitAllReady()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(all_ready, INFINITE);
}

void CGameHost::ReleaseRead()
{
    ReleaseSemaphore(read, 1, NULL);
}

void CGameHost::WaitAllRead()
{
    WaitForSingleObject(all_read, INFINITE);
}
```

`DataProcess::Game` is the message handler for incoming game messages.

```
CMessage Dataprocess::Game( CMessage* recv_msg )
{
    CMessage ret;
    int now_roomnum = recv_msg->para1;
    int now_playernum = recv_msg->para2;
    if(true)
    {
        cout<<"Received Game Message: "<<endl;
        cout<<"type2 = "<<recv_msg->type2;
        cout<<" player_num = "<<now_playernum<<" msg= "<<recv_msg->msg<<endl;
    }

    if(recv_msg->type2 == MSG_GAME_OPERATION)
    {
        ret.type1 = MSG_GAME;
        ret.type2 = MSG_GAME_OPERATION;

        cout<<"Entered from "<<now_playernum<<endl;

        game_host[now_roomnum].SetMessage(now_playernum, recv_msg->msg);
        game_host[now_roomnum].ReleaseReady();

        cout<<"Released Ready from "<<now_playernum<<endl;//this is shown

        game_host[now_roomnum].WaitAllReady();//stuck here

        cout<<"AllReady from"<<now_playernum<<endl;//not shown

    }
    return ret;
}
```

Your reply will be of great help for a beginner of Windows multithread programmer like me! Thank you!

Comment: What you probably want is to use WaitForMultipleObjects

Comment: Umm... IOCP doesn't imply that every message is processed on a separate thread. Perhaps you should include your IOCP code as well?

Comment: Looks to me like you are deadlocking your message handler.  No more messages can be processed as soon as the 1st player is ready.  You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: @Luaan To be honest, IOCP part is not written by me... so I don't know what part should be posted...

Comment: @HansPassant But if the 1st player is ready, the monitor thread should capture a `ready` and display a "Get Ready!" while I did not see this message at all.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto Is there any differences? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it myself. The reason is that I used `CreateSemaphore` again after creating the thread, making the player thread visiting different semaphores as the monitor thread... Sorry for my stupidness, and thank you for telling me so much!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your needs, you should probably have something like this..

HANDLE hPlayersReady[4];
HANDLE hAllPlayed;

Create these 5 events, and then on your monitor thread,
do something like this...

```
while(true)
{
// Wait for all players to move
WaitForMultipleObjects(4, &hPlayersReady, true, INFINITE);
// Process move
...
// Advise players the move was processed...
SetEvent(hAllPlayed);
}
```

And on your player thread X

```
while(true)
{
// Make my move
...
// Advise monitor I'm ready
SetEvent(hPlayersReady[X]);
// Wait for ready to do another move
WaitForSingleObject(hAllPlayed);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't think it will work because `hAllPlayed` have to be taken for 4 times and I wonder if it can only be read for once...

Comment: Looks like you'll have to explain the difference between a semaphore and an event.

Comment: @DarkZero, I didn't get your comment, what do you mean with "have to be taken for 4 times" ?

Comment: In this game, four players will post their actions to the server every frame, so there are four threads storing their actions and asking for all actions. For example, player 1 will tell the server his actions, and he will ask for all players' actions, so do player 2 3 4, so everyone will wait for hAllPlayed to continue, thus waiting it for 4 times.

Comment: @DarkZero, the hAllPlayed must be created with a "manual reset" and then you would need a "acknowledge" response trigerred from the threads in order for the monitor thread to do the reset.